# How to group by with left join by multiple columns using linq and get count of grouped records?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-6

Lets say we have:
**Employee** class (prop: EmployeeID, EmployeeName, DepartmentID, Department - as navigation prop) and **Department** class (prop: DepartmentID, DepartmentName, Employees - as navigation prop).
The relationship between this two tables is one to many.
Now the concrete example:

**Employee** table

```
EmployeeID EmployeeName DepartmentID     
1          Peter        1               
2          Anna         1                
3          John         2
```

**Department** table

```
DepartmentID  DepartmentName                                                        
1             IT                                                                    
2             Marketing                                                              
3             HR
```

The final result should be showing every department (DepartmentID, DepartmentName, NumOfEmployees) regardless does it have an employees with number of employees in the department, for example: 1, IT, 2 | 2, Marketing, 1 | 3, HR, 0.

My syntax was:

```
var dbContext.Departments.Include(d => d.Employees).    
                          GroupBy(d => new { d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName }).
                          Select(x => new {
                                   DepartmentID = x.Key.DepartmentID,
                                   DepartmentName = x.Key.DepartmentName,
                                   NumOfEmployees = x.Count()
    }).ToList();
```

The problem is that attribute NumOfEmployees is assigned with 1 for every department, and don't know why.
How would correct lambda expression LINQ syntax look like?

Comment: You are grouping departments and then counting them, so you get `1`'s. `Include` is de-facto ignored cause you have `Select` statement. Also why do you need to group by `ID` and `Name`?

Comment: Don't you want just `NumOfEmployees = x.Employees.Count()`?

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto I assume because it will not compile, cause `IGrouping` does not have `Employees` property.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto It does not work what you suggested, because x has no Employees as suggestion.

Comment: That is because `x` (better named `dg`) is an `IGrouping` with one member (the department record) so if you did `x.First().Employees.Count()` you would get an answer. Imagine you took out the `Include` and the `Select` then you have `dbContext.Departments.GroupBy(d => new { d.DepartmentID, d.DepartmentName })` - what would you expect to be in each group?

Comment: @NetMage I assume it would be DepartmentID and DepartmentName of each department record

Comment: That would be the `Key` of the `IGrouping` - what would be its contents?

Comment: @NetMage Perhaps concrete values of those Key attrbutes?

Comment: I don't think you understand `GroupBy`. Fundamentally an `IGrouping` is an object with a `Key` property (that is an object) and is also a collection of objects. So `Departments.GroupBy` will return groups of departments (`IGrouping<Department>`) and each group will be all departments with the same `DepartmentID` and `DepartmentName` based on your lambda - which means each group will have one `Department` object in it. Hence, its `Count()` is one.

Answer (score 2):

I would say that you don't need `GroupBy` here and can do as simple as:

```
var result = dbContext.Departments
    .Select(x => new 
    {
        DepartmentID = x.DepartmentID,
        DepartmentName = x.DepartmentName,
        NumOfEmployees = x.Employees.Count()
    })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: It will work, for sure, but I wanted to use group by in order to get count of grouped records

Comment: @szti1516 what do you mean by "grouped"? Grouping will give you the same results here, if your ids for  `Departments` are unique in database.

Comment: I wanted to use group by to practice some group by examples. The way you posted is correct, but I wanted to do with group by.

Comment: @szti1516 there is absolutely no point grouping departments here. If you want to practice group by you need either group employees or join departments and employees and group the result.

Comment: If I wanted to group by on Employee.EmployeeName and Department.DepartmenName collumns, how would be lambda expression look:var dbContext.Departments.Include(d => d.Employees).GroupBy(d => new { d.DepartmentName, d.Employees }).ToList(); Cause I suppose this is not correct syntax?.

Comment: @szti1516 let's start from another end. What SQL query you want to get? Also it seems that you are misunderstanding `Include`. It will join data only for selection, not the query itself. If you want  `join` you need to perform join either with `Queryable.Join` or query syntax `join`.

Comment: I want query which will group based on EmployeeName from Employee and DepartmenName from Department and I want NumOfEmployees who are in that group. I wonder what the correct syntax would look? Is the syntax I wrote in the previous post correct?

Comment: @szti1516 Your query only groups departments by their unique IDs and counts *departments* in each group. `NumOfEmployees` is actually `NumOfDepartments`, and yes, it's always 1. In other words, there's no better way than in this answer.